# JS run function with perfect interval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to run a command every 25 milliseconds. The problem with `setInterval` or `setTimeout` is that they don't run exactly every 25 milliseconds. How can I make the interval exact?

Comment: Maybe try requestAnimationFrame

Comment: It is impossible to be perfect with setInterval and setTimeout.

Comment: You cannot do this exactly because the agent in which JavaScript runs (browser) will have other things to do, and the same is true for the operating system on which that agent runs. And perfection would need a perfect clock.

Comment: What is the ultimate need? Browsers aren't hard-real-time, no matter what, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: I am trying to make a game and I want to update player positions every 25 milliseconds or so. I am doing this on nodejs.

Comment: The modern consumer operating systems do not provide support for what you want.

Comment: You can use setImmediate and try to get it as close as possible with looking at date diffs, but it will still not be 100% accurate since it is still just scheduling it to run the next available time.

Comment: Jake and Surma recently did a Video about timers: https://youtu.be/MCi6AZMkxcU

Comment: "[...] 25 milliseconds or so" is different than "exactly every 25 ms". Your *best* bet is to use a game library instead of reinventing that wheel yet again (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) method. Its a simple polling based loop, suited for developing games like yourself.

You can use this somewhat crude implementation.

```js
const element = document.getElementById('some-element-you-want-to-animate');
let start;
let cycleCount = 0;

// Set this variable to true when you want to end the loop
let cyclesSetToEnd = false;

// Define the resolution per cycle.
// Number of 1ms cycles after which doSomething is executed.
const resolutionFactor = 25000;

function step(timestamp) {
  if (start === undefined)
    start = timestamp;
  const elapsed = timestamp - start;

  // Check if elapsed time has hit a second
  if (elapsed % resolutionTime > cycleCount) {
    cycleCount = elapsed % resolutionTime;
    // Do time-sensitive update here
    doSomething();
  }

  if (!cyclesSetToEnd) { // Stop the animation after 20 seconds
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

The timestamp passed to `step` method is a [DOMHighResTimestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) which

> ...SHOULD represent a time in milliseconds accurate to 5 microseconds...
>
> NOTE
>
> If the User Agent is unable to provide a time value accurate to 5 microseconds due to hardware or software constraints, the User Agent can represent a DOMHighResTimeStamp as a time in milliseconds accurate to a millisecond.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but unfortunately, the question asks about a Node.js context, which doesn't have `requestAnimationFrame` (since it [doesn't have a context in which to render animations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30442896/710446)).